# Getting a external programs handle

Tags: c++, winapi

I made a small program in C++ that can type text into a notepad document, it does so using FindWindow and FindWindowEx, but I was only able to do that because I knew the names of the windows I was trying to access (in this case it was "Notepad" for the doc and "Edit" for the text area).

If I didn't know the names how would I go about figuring that out? Lets hypothetically say I wanted to make text appear in Chrome's URL box, how would I figure out what the name of that box is so I can use FindWindowEx on it?

Comment: Maybe use a `GetFocus` function instead? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646294(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Spy++ may help you narrow it down a bit.

Comment: @Fiz: there is no such function, and even if there were, it would not make sense. A process can have multiple windows.

Comment: What is your goal? It sounds like you want to do automated UI testing. Is this the case? For UI test automation there are libraries that would do this for you. If not, clarify what your scenario is.

Comment: You are doing this the wrong way. You should be automating the UI rather than poking messages at windows.

Answer (score 2):

The least painful approach to automating 3rd party applications is to use [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684009.aspx). It allows you to navigate UI hierarchies as well as operate on the individual objects.

All native windows controls support UI Automation out of the box. UI Automation also works with frameworks, that do not implement their UI using native controls (e.g. Qt). Particularly with Qt, tools like Spy++ will not give you the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Run the other app and then use a tool like Spy++, Winspector, etc to look at the other program's window hierarchy to find what you need.